# How to decimate enemy armies without mutilating them?

Tags: biology, creature-design, evolution, xenobiology, fauna

Everyone could agree that smashing a sword or shooting an arrow onto your plate of food is not the brightest idea, but vampires are even more extreme.
Vampires eat like spiders, they inject a substance onto the body of their victims which reacts with blood creating an acid which pre-digests the victim. Severed victims who experienced serious blood loss would only be partially digested or raw. Plus if someone is missing their head or a limb, most of the acid would leak out.

Vampires do not have particular super powers,other than perfect night vision and Incredible leaping powers, a vampire can jump 1.5  metres high from standing. Oh and they don't age obviously! But other than that they are vulnerable to being killed normally.
[image]

They all look like the average aristocratic figure and they probably invented BDSM, oh and they have freakish red eyes! Not just a normal red, but brilliant red!

Knowing that I still question how do vampires wage wars without severing limbs and causing important blood loss on their enemies/meals ? It must be a method which is really effective since it was used through most of vampire history and evolution, and over the eons people hardly adapted to counteract the vampires.

**edit**

In combat between to factions one made of normal humans and the other made of vampires as described above, how does the vampire faction defeat the human armies without causing damages which would result in serious blood loss?

Comment: You don't wage a war because you want to loot some swords from the battlefield; a vampire wouldn't pitch a battle because they're hungry. A good meal from captured soldiers might be a nice bonus, but they're probably not fighting for food specifically, it's too unreliable a supply.

Comment: When was "severing limbs and causing important blood loss" a valid battle tactic *ever*? The purpose of a battle is to force the enemy to concede an objective which is considered important; an obligate passage point, a city, control over an area, and so on. In most battles, most of the time, dead soldiers died with their limbs attached and most of the blood still in their bodies. (For a brief period of time, roughly from 1600 to about 1920, limb loss was quite common, due to the use of massed infantry in the presence of cannon and machine guns. But even then most soldiers did not lose limbs.)

Comment: blunt weapon ? such as mace,club,hammer,maul etc. also maybe choke them to death using rope or whip assuming their neck unarmored. and as AlexP say during war people wear armor for a reason. limbs severed is rare, usually happen against sleeveless or unarmored against better cutting power that beat their shield such as roman during dacian war.

Comment: The world [world record for standing high jump](https://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/highest-standing-jump) is 1.651m, maybe 1.5m isn't "incredible leaping powers"

Comment: @ThePainfull that's a world record, average trained humans have a standing jump of 50 centimetres... Just like how the average human bench press is 70 kilograms but the world record is 350 kilograms...world records are...uhm, far from average.

Comment: Yeah yeah i know, 1.5m just seemed a bit tame for "incredible leaping powers", but i get your point.

Comment: @ThePainfull Tbf, that does open an opportunity for well trained humans to be able to match an average vampire's skill, which could be very beneficial story-wise.

Comment: 'Decimate' means to kill one in ten.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond Correct, but still "being decimated" sounds worse than "being cut in half", funny how that works.

Comment: @Douwe Whatever happened to the word 'devastate'? When did that become politically incorrect? It was at one time a perfectly good word for describing 'wide scale destruction'.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond This word is probably the most commonly cited illustration of the "etymological fallacy", conflating a word's origins with current meaning. In current use, decimate more commonly means "kill, destroy, or remove a large percentage or part of.", "reduce drastically especially in number." etc, and OP used it correctly. See also myriad only means 10k, gay only means happy, orient only means "face east", caption = "text over a picture", awful = awesome, fantastic = imaginary, etc.

Comment: If you didn't draw the art, please provide credit where credit is due. If you did draw the art - dang.

Comment: Also, I like the question, but it's too broad and, IMO, the wrong starting point. I therefore must VTC:NMF. I suggest you edit your post to reduce the question to: in combat between two people and given A is armed with X and B is armed with Y, what tactics could B use to subdue A that does not result in a severed limb?"

Comment: You don't need to just keep the bodies intact, you need to keep them *alive*. Your method of digestion requires that blood circulate through the body, so a vampire will be unable to digest a corpse.  You not only need to win a war without severing limbs, you need to do it *without killing*.

Comment: @Dewi Morgan Someone actually addressed this problem in a recent OP, about how long a language can remain pure. 'Decimate' still has 'deci' and 'mate' , booth of which have retained their original meanings. It has nothing to do with the etymological fallacy, and everything to do with the bastardization of American English. Every non-American English  word has to be given an American definition and made American.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond - I am British. In a quick check, American dictionaries (eg M-W) seem more likely to list your "remove a tenth" meaning as the first meaning, and not to list it as archaic or obsolete. I cannot find any dictionary anywhere that listed it as the only possible meaning. Your citing the word stems is canonical etymological fallacy at work.

Comment: @Dewi Morgan So an 'octogenarian' can be a 70 year old, a 'hexagon' can be a five sided figure, and a 'decimal' can be a base 12 number, just because someone wants them to mean that? And to claim otherwise is simply a canonical etymological fallacy? The meaning of 'decimate' is in the compound word, not the etymology. 'Deci' is ten, 'mate' is a person. 'Octo' is 80, 'genarian' is the generation. Etymology has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond Yes, if those became the common usages, that's exactly the case. See the names of the months for a case where exactly what you described has happened. You also appear unfamiliar with the meaning of the term "etymological fallacy", so here's a link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymological_fallacy

Comment: @Dewi Morgan  And thus we have the reason for the continuation of the degradation of literacy. Word definitions sink to the lowest common determinator. The etymologiocal fallacy is all about making excuses for declining educational standards and rewarding ignorance, not about human progress. When mathematical preciseness becomes meaningless, stupidity reins.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond Reigns*.

Answer (score 10):

Vampires might like to eat their enemies.  But they don't eat enemies on the battle field.  Someone will come up and kick them, hard.   It is analogous to soldiers who have sex with their captives, or members of a conquered population.  Those soldiers are not having sex with enemies on the battlefield.  I don't think.  Not in a pitched battle anyway.

Vampires make war the same way fancy folks do anything grubby and distasteful: they have someone else do it.  Vampires usually are in leadership positions and so deploy armies of humans which use the standard tactics of the day.  Just as victorious armies evaluate the conquered for persons of interest (for example, the Mongols looked for craftsmen) so too your vampires peruse the conquered for persons of interest to them.

Answer (score 5):

### Prisoners

Casualities in battles are usually quite low. Most of casualities occure during rout, and even then, only a small portion of soldiers die, the majority is either captured, or managed to flee.

Don't worry about killing some of the soldiers, if it's the only mean to capture a larger part of them.

And don't worry about holywood-style last stand, not only they are rare in history, but if beeing captured mean death with a painless poison, just after a BDSM experience, lot of folks would prefer that instead of fighting to the last and endure a long, painfull death

Answer (score 5):

**Mace**

Humanity (and vampirity) has always been very inventive in killing others, and while swords, daggers and arrows have always been a staple of warfare, they are far from the only options. There is an entire arsenal of weapons available that is used to inflict blunt force trauma, which will typically cause *internal* bleeding and fractures, but will keep "the blood in the bag" so to speak.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mace_(bludgeon))

> During the Middle Ages metal armour such as mail protected against the
> blows of edged weapons.[2] Solid metal maces and war hammers proved
> able to inflict damage on well armoured knights, as the force of a
> blow from a mace is great enough to cause damage without penetrating
> the armour.

So where prehistoric humans might use a stone axe on the battlefield, a prehistoric vampire would rather use a club, so as to not spoil their meal. In the middle ages it's swords for the humans and mace for the vampires, and moving on to the modern age, vampires now have a myriad of options available to them including (but not limited to) gases, bombs that kill through shock wave rather than shrapnel, biological agents etc. etc.

Also, vampires *fight mean*. Just like we don't care about our honor when killing the animals we eat, vampires do not care how we die, as long as their meal isn't spoiled. No vampire ever cosigned the Geneva convention. This means that if they can gas, trap, drown or burn (hmmm, crispy) their prey without even confronting them, they will. Vampires are evil after all.

Answer (score 5):

If vampires are eating entire armies and so much so that they want to conserve blood from every single soldier -- your vampires aren't going to last long.  They are obviously running through their food source with such speed that they will exterminate humanity and then starve.

Predators must be seriously out-numbered by prey.

Consequently, how are they going to work out how to do this before it's moot?

Edit:  As a logical consequence, the actual reaction of sensible vampires to war is to make peace by whatever means will work.  Magic?  Use it.  Negotiations?  Use them.  Treachery?  Use it.  Anything to keep the sheep docile so you can fleece them, instead of watching them stampede into a marsh and drown.

Comment: Humans are considered a "reward" precious meal...just like how some people organize hunts for dangerous wild game.

Comment: Or how all cannibal tribes also eat other foods

Comment: Cannibal tribes fight their wars like everyone else -- without vast concern for the meat they are wasting.  And hunters may prize their trophies from lions, but if they were attacked by a megapride of lions, their concern would be killing them all and not preserving the trophies.

Answer (score 4):

I present to you: war hammers and maces.

[Maces](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mace_(bludgeon)) and [war hammers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_hammer) have been used since before the modern ages, so they should accessible to your vampires. Both of these weapons are blunt (have blunt variants, as both also have spiked variants which could easily pierce the enemy with enough force), usually useful against armored enemies and what's best in your case: will likely cause fractures and internal bleeding, ensuring that acid of yours reach better every single crevice in the body (plus, if they invented BDSM, they might be into having their enemies agonizing in the ground because their limbs were smashed with a hammer or club). Dealing with archery might not be too much of a problem if they are skilled enough, as a well shot arrow can kill a knight with minimal blood loss. If your vampires have good vision, they might want to take aim and take down the more troublesome looking enemies from afar.

For better reference, though more centered around more classic vampires and in a more individual perspective, [this video from Shadiversity](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DTX0qlsV1Yxk&ved=2ahUKEwjM4OnopYvqAhWWEbkGHdZ4DCUQo7QBMAF6BAgCEAE&usg=AOvVaw2Y0akGFUKD5sAJ934xiZYy) actually explores this concept of the weapon most suited to incapacitate an enemy with minimal blood loss.

Comment: blunt arrow exist anyway, outside of throwing stone either manually or using tool such as sling, regarding range weapon.

Comment: @Li Jun I don't know enough about slings to determine if they could have strong enough power and enough range to be worth using, which is why I didn't include them.

Comment: Seems you posted your answer while I was writing mine :/ Excellent idea though, have an upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

**Cauterize open wounds with hot metal**

As Kepotx said in [their answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/178846/66146), the actual ratio of fatality is actually quite low in a battle, leaving you with plenty of wounded prisoners.

If you're just gonna eat them, you could simply cauterize all open wounds with red-hot metal and stop blood loss like that. It's not gonna do much to save the lives of the wounded, as infections are the primary cause of death. But it'll keep them alive a few hours to a few days depending on the severity of the wound, and it should keep the blood inside the body long enough for the venom to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the mace and hammer would be what vampires would use. even better would be a steel quarterstaff, which in the hands of a creature such as vampire, would be far deadlier.

as a matter of fact, i saw a video by Shad Brooks about what weapons vampires would actually use:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TX0qlsV1Yxk&list=PLWklwxMTl4sxf_Yvz8ePW7tcpDnhGpKV_&index=34